# how to make SVG show a specific number of the path inside it

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to show specific numbers of stars inside a div

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 206 38" class="star-rating star-off">
<path d="M31.86,1H6.14A5.15,5.15,0,0,0,1,6.14V31.86A5.15,5.enter code here15,0,0,0,6.14,37H31.86A5.15,5.15,0,0,0,37,31.86V6.14A5.15,5.15,0,0,0,31.86,1Zm-7.3,27L19,24.93,13.44,28l1.06-6.51L10,16.88l6.22-.95L19,10l2.78,5.93,6.22.95-4.5,4.61Z"></path>
<path d="M73.86,1H48.14A5.15,5.15,0,0,0,43,6.14V31.86A5.15,5.15,0,0,0,48.14,37H73.86A5.15,5.15,0,0,0,79,31.86V6.14A5.15,5.15,0,0,0,73.86,1Zm-7.3,27L61,24.93,55.44,28l1.06-6.51L52,16.88l6.22-.95L61,10l2.78,5.93,6.22.95-4.5,4.61Z"></path>
<path d="M115.86,1H90.14A5.15,5.15,0,0,0,85,6.14V31.86A5.15,5.15,0,0,0,90.14,37h25.72A5.15,5.15,0,0,0,121,31.86V6.14A5.15,5.15,0,0,0,115.86,1Zm-7.3,27L103,24.93,97.44,28l1.06-6.51L94,16.88l6.22-.95L103,10l2.78,5.93,6.22.95-4.5,4.61Z"></path>
<path d="M157.86,1H132.14A5.15,5.15,0,0,0,127,6.14V31.86A5.15,5.15,0,0,0,132.14,37h25.72A5.15,5.15,0,0,0,163,31.86V6.14A5.15,5.15,0,0,0,157.86,1Zm-7.3,27L145,24.93,139.44,28l1.06-6.51L136,16.88l6.22-.95L145,10l2.78,5.93,6.22.95-4.5,4.61Z"></path>
<path d="M199.86,1H174.14A5.15,5.15,0,0,0,169,6.14V31.86A5.15,5.15,0,0,0,174.14,37h25.72A5.15,5.15,0,0,0,205,31.86V6.14A5.15,5.15,0,0,0,199.86,1Zm-7.3,27L187,24.93,181.44,28l1.06-6.51L178,16.88l6.22-.95L187,10l2.78,5.93,6.22.95-4.5,4.61Z"></path>
Tags
```

Comment: So what do you want in terms of asp.net and c#?

Comment: Your svg lacks a close tag </svg> and it contains 5 symbols, 4 are stars. The left symbol is non-star, so your first star coordinate is (73,86). I think this svg - as is - is not suitable for placing a number of stars in a div.

Answer (score 0):

Nesting the svg-tag allows for positioning, refer to

https://www.jotform.com/blog/better-positioning-and-transforming-with-nested-svgs/

I used only the first star from your SVG and placed 3 stars in a DIV, with relative "x" and "y"coordinates.

Below is my html. Put the div part in your .cshtml and handle the case for 1,2,3,4 stars, e.g. using @if (condition) {}

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 206 38" class="star-rating star-off">
  <svg x="-35" y="0"> 
    <path d="M73.86,1H48.14A5.15,5.15,0,0,0,43,6.14V31.86A5.15,5.15,0,0,0,48.14,37H73.86A5.15,5.15,0,0,0,79,31.86V6.14A5.15,5.15,0,0,0,73.86,1Zm-7.3,27L61,24.93,55.44,28l1.06-6.51L52,16.88l6.22-.95L61,10l2.78,5.93,6.22.95-4.5,4.61Z"></path>
  </svg>
  <svg x="5" y="0"> 
    <path d="M73.86,1H48.14A5.15,5.15,0,0,0,43,6.14V31.86A5.15,5.15,0,0,0,48.14,37H73.86A5.15,5.15,0,0,0,79,31.86V6.14A5.15,5.15,0,0,0,73.86,1Zm-7.3,27L61,24.93,55.44,28l1.06-6.51L52,16.88l6.22-.95L61,10l2.78,5.93,6.22.95-4.5,4.61Z"></path>
  </svg>
  <svg x="45" y="0"> 
    <path d="M73.86,1H48.14A5.15,5.15,0,0,0,43,6.14V31.86A5.15,5.15,0,0,0,48.14,37H73.86A5.15,5.15,0,0,0,79,31.86V6.14A5.15,5.15,0,0,0,73.86,1Zm-7.3,27L61,24.93,55.44,28l1.06-6.51L52,16.88l6.22-.95L61,10l2.78,5.93,6.22.95-4.5,4.61Z"></path>
  </svg>
 </svg>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```